# Can Isa (as) be considered as a son of Adam?

Tags: prophet-isa

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Can Prophet Isa ibn Maryam (as) be considered one amongst the Bani Adam?

What i mean is, is it correct to believe that Isa(as) is also made of Mud/clay just like every other human?

Comment: it is possible for him to not be from Bani Adam (genetically) but still made of clay. So it is not correct to think if we ansewer your first question as "true" that this means the second will also be "true".

Comment: Isa was the biological son of Maryam, who was a daughter of Adam. So what is the obstacle to him being considered a son of Adam?